# Smtp email sending fails for some addresses with weird smtp logs

Tags: c#, smtp, smtpclient

I'm seeing a weird issue where emails are sent to most email addresses, but fail for some with this exception

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

SMTP logs for a successful email send (sensitive data removed)

```
Connected to smtp://HOST_NAME_GOES_HERE:25/?starttls=when-available
S: 220 HOST_ID.mail.protection.outlook.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Thu, 8 Jul 2021 16:17:25 +0000
C: EHLO [INNER_HOST_IP]
S: 250-HOST_ID.mail.protection.outlook.com Hello [HOST_IP]
S: 250-SIZE 157286400
S: 250-PIPELINING
S: 250-DSN
S: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
S: 250-STARTTLS
S: 250-8BITMIME
S: 250-BINARYMIME
S: 250-CHUNKING
S: 250 SMTPUTF8
C: STARTTLS
S: 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
C: EHLO [INNER_HOST_IP]
S: 250-HOST_ID.mail.protection.outlook.com Hello [HOST_IP]
S: 250-SIZE 157286400
S: 250-PIPELINING
S: 250-DSN
S: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
S: 250-8BITMIME
S: 250-BINARYMIME
S: 250-CHUNKING
S: 250 SMTPUTF8
C: MAIL FROM:<FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS> SIZE=1449
C: RCPT TO:<TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS>
S: 250 2.1.0 Sender OK
S: 250 2.1.5 Recipient OK
C: DATA
S: 354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>
C: From: FROM_NAME <FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS>
C: To: TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS
C: Subject: Email Subject
C: Date: Thu, 08 Jul 2021 16:17:26 +0000
C: MIME-Version: 1.0
C: Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
C: 
C: <html>
C: <body>
C: <p>Hello</p>
C: .
S: 250 2.6.0 <13ca1966-3710-4ac5-89a1-0307450df835@IDENTIFIER.eop-EUR01.prod.protection.outlook.com> [InternalId=6373731476739, Hostname=IDENTIFIER.GBRP265.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM] 9026 bytes in 0.121, 72.458 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery
```

But when sending to an email that fails, the only thing that appears in smtp logs is

```
C: MAIL FROM:<FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS> SIZE=1475
C: RCPT TO:<TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS>
```

Does anyone know what this means, or how I can go about debugging it?

The email is being sent via c# SmtpClient, and as mentioned is working for most emails.

Answer (score 1):

The reality of network programming is that you will get errors like:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

from time to time and the only thing you can do about it is to reconnect and try again.

The error has nothing to do with the email address. It's just an error that occurs when a TCP/IP connection times out because the remote host failed to respond in a timely manner (usually because the connection was lost somehow).

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, it does seem that this happens frequently from emails from a specific domain though, where gmail or another ogs emails are very reliably receiving the emails. Could the only explanation really only be that it co-incidentally times out for that domain?

Comment: Maybe your SMTP server tries to do a DNS lookup of domains to see if they are available and that DNS lookup times out?